# How can a non-dense, well-ordered set like a long ray be uncountable?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

How can a non-dense, well-ordered set like a long ray be uncountable? If it's a set of an uncountable number of [0,1) line segments laid end to end, shouldn't there be a bijective function between the COUNTABLE set of natural numbers and the n-th segment on the ray? Is its very existence not a contradiction?

Comment: No; why on earth should there be? There is not just an $n$-th segment for every $n\in\Bbb N$; there is an $\alpha$-th segment for every $\alpha\in\omega_1$, and $\omega_1$ is uncountable.

Comment: That makes sense... it's a little counter-intuitive to think of set theory in a physical sort context. I suppose the problem there is visualization. Thank you, that helped a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the long line is to take $\omega_1$ copies of $[0,1)$. If the [non-negative] real numbers can be thought of as a countable union of $[0,1)$ ordered lexicographically, the idea behind the *long* line is that we take even more.

The fact that there are uncountable sets which are well-ordered follows from the axioms of ZF, it does not even require the axiom of choice.

The long line, if so, is **not** like a subset of the real numbers. It is a whole other topological space. In that space there is an uncountable well-ordered set, whereas in the real numbers every set which is well-ordered [in the natural order of the real numbers] is countable.